# Browser timing out JavaScript recursive function, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, browser, timeout, mootools, ping

I had to develop a newsletter manager with JS + PHP + MYSQL and I would like to know a few things on browser timing out the JS functions. If I'm running a recursive function that delays a call to itself (while PHP returns a list of email), how can I be sure that the browser won't timeout this JS function ?

I'm asking this, because I remember using a similar newsletter manager, that while doing the ajax requests, after a few calls, it stopped without any apparent reason. I know JS is not meant for this, and I should use Crontab on server, but, I can't assume the users server handles cron, so I had to stick with JS + php.

PS - This didn't happened on this app yet, I'm just trying to prevent the worse of the scenarios (since I've tested a newsletter manager, that worked the same as this one I'm developing). Since my dummy email list is small and the delays between calls are also small, this works just fine, but let's imagine a 1,000 contact list, with a delay between sends of 120 seconds: Sending 30 emails for each 2 minutes.

By the way, why this ? Well, many hosting servers has a limit on emails sent per day or hour and this helps preventing violating that policy.

Comment: I guess I could just ask to, tips on how to keep alive on browser a recursive javascript script, that call itself with a long delay?

Comment: If you post an example of the sort of code you're talking about, then people might be able to help. "Timing out recursive functions" doesn't make sense (to me at least).

Comment: Also, it's not "recursion" when a timeout function sets itself up for another timeout. I'm not familiar with any browser that refuses to honor timeout handlers (unless the calling page goes away, of course).

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking.

Let's say:

Function countdown ( Nr_of_seconds );

Function sendEmailToList( list_Of_Emails, nr_of_emails_per_count ) {

if countdown( 30 seconds ) ends then
if is true emails exist -> sendEmails( nr_of_emails_per_count )
remove ( nr of emails per count ) from list of emails
Sendemailtolist again
};

Comment: the previous pseudo code,

http://pastie.org/1026617

Answer (score 0):

from the mootools standpoint, there are several possible solutions here.

- request.periodical - http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.Periodical

has plenty of options that allow for handling batches of jobs, look at it like a more complex .periodical (setInterval) that understands async nature of the result and can compensate for lag etc. I think it can literally do what you set in your requirements out of the box, all you need is an oncomplete callback that clears up the done from your pending array (for eg).

- request.queue - http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.Queue

basically, setup all your requests to handle the chunks of data and pass them on to Request.Queue to handle sequentially. Probably less sophisticated from the point of view of sending rate control.

Answer (score 0):

How about a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). That will not cause a timeout in your javascript function. You Just reload your page after a specific time and then send the next emails out. Adding a parameter to the URL you can find out which "round" you are on.

Can this do the job for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setTimeOut. The code needs to yield control to the UI thread and let the browser become responsive to avoid the script from being stopped.

Read this post by Nick Z.
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/

There is also something the W3C Spec about this called "Efficient Script Yielding" I'm not sure how far along it is or if any browsers support it.
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/setImmediate/Overview.html

You could also try HTML5 Web Workers.